# PHP - ZipArchive is enabled but not found

Tags: linux, php-ziparchive, php

When I look at `phpinfo` I see that Zip is enabled:
[image]

```
extension_loaded('zip') // <- returns true.
function_exists('zip_open') // <- returns true.
class_exists('ZipArchive', false) // <-returns false.
```

When I try to create a ZipArchive object, I get error: `Fatal error:  Class 'ZipArchive' not found`

PHP Version 5.4.11

Comment: what's your PHP version?

Comment: @JurisMalinens: that probably won't help, since he would be getting something like `"Class 'my\namespace\ZipArchive' not found"` if it were a namespace issue...

Comment: are you using xampp,wamp,... or php alone?

Comment: what about other zip functions? What does `var_dump(function_exists('zip_open'));` say?

Comment: It returns `bool(true)` so does `extension_loaded('zip')`

Comment: `class_exists('ZipArchive', false)` returns false

Comment: are you run commands in command line? maybe `zip` extension is not loaded for command line.

Comment: I just do what @Juris Malinens said, just put a leading backslash "\" before ZipArchive ;)
Since I've got the same issu as you

Answer (score 3):

Found the fix by reading this [mediatemple kb article.](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1682/Installing+PECL+extensions#dv)  I already had zip.so in /usr/lib64/php/modules/

Thing missing was `extension=zip.so` entry in php.ini

After adding that entry and restarting Apache, ZipArchive is now recognized.